# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

### com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`storechainmanagement`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) at com.azilen.storemanagement.dao.StoreManagementDaoImpl.saveManager(StoreManagementDaoImpl.java:323) at com.azilen.storemanagement.service.StoreManagementServiceImpl.addManager(StoreManagementServiceImpl.java:35) at com.azilen.storemanagement.controller.CreateUserServlet.doPost(CreateUserServlet.java:51) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
@Override
public int saveManager(Manager manager) throws SQLException {
    int status = 0;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into user(user_id,first_name,last_name,email,password,mobile_number,user_type,store_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, (int) manager.getUserId());
        ps.setString(2, manager.getFname());
        ps.setString(3, manager.getLname());
        ps.setString(4, manager.getEmail());
        ps.setString(5, manager.getPassword());
        ps.setString(6, manager.getPhone());
        ps.setString(7, manager.getUserType());
        ps.setInt(8, (int) manager.getStore().getStoreId());
        status = ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: To find an answer your question, you must add your database table structure and java code blocks

Comment: CONSTRAINT  refers your user table check your user table if user exist before insert shipping inser or update

Comment: yes it exists and the stores table also exist with the data of foreign key also exist in the following table

Comment: _okay thank you for your help i got the answer i was doing wrong in my code for setting the values in the bean_